# SSRS reports clipped in IE9 but fine in IE8

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, browser, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have one page called `Reports.aspx` which contains one `IFrame` and I have put one user control into that `IFrame`.

That `IFrame` have the reports to show but in `IE9` the report become clipped i.e. showing partially but if I run the same in `IE8` then everything is fine.

Now I want to render the Iframe part in `IE8` but the rest aspx page in `IE9`. Will it be possible?

Hope so....

Comment: I would imagine that the IFrame would inherit from the parent.  The better solution is to fix your clipping issue in IE9.

Answer (score 1):

Render the page using a meta tag seen hear

```
<html>
   <head>
   <!-- Mimic Internet Explorer 8 -->
      <title>My Web Page</title>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Content goes here.</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

IE Rendering Modes: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/03/23/understanding-compatibility-modes-in-internet-explorer-8.aspx

I have no idea if this is possible, I've never tried it, but enclose IFrame in metatag to just have it render as IE8.

Edit:

try this in your IFrame:

```
<html>
       <head>
       <!-- Mimic Internet Explorer 8 -->
          <title>My Web Page</title>
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
       </head>
    <iframe>
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
            </head>
            </html>
        </iframe>
</html>
```

There is an issue with this style for changing documents mode but I doubt that is what your doing

Comment: Did you try just putting it in the user control? Then on the page make it render in IE9 by explicitly stating so IE=9. But as @javisrk suggested the IFrame might still inherit from parent. But it's worth a shot

Answer (score 0):

After a long search I have found the solution to show SSRS report in IE9 by the following tricks :

First I have rendered the IFrame in IE8 (http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8") and as a result the whole page renders in IE8 which distorted some of my CSS 3.0 styles like rounded corner, box effects, shadows etc. To overcome this I have used http://css3pie.com/ and my problem solved...

Although css3Pie have some limitations but it works for me on this scenario.

Hope this will help someone.